# How to program Button to change function depending on integer variable in SharedPreferences

Tags: android, button, sharedpreferences

I have a simple game that I am writing to learn programming.  At the end, I want the final button to go to different endings based on the "score" which is an integer variable saved in the sharedpref.

My approach has been to set up an "if/else if" loop that edits a string shared pref called "page" and then applies the "page" to the button action. What is clear is that my if/else if loop is NOT editing the "page" sharedpref, because the button keeps using the prior value.

Here's my attempt at code; thanks for ANY help!

```
public Button button;


public void init() {

    button=findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("ScorePref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        int score = pref.getInt("Score", 0); 
        //these two lines recall the "score" integer

        SharedPreferences saveGame = getSharedPreferences("PrefFile", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String page = saveGame.getString
                ("page", "com.twigofknowledge.variablebuttonpractice.MainActivity");
        //and then the two above here recall the "page" string sharedpref

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = saveGame.edit();
        //this is the editor that will change the sharedpref

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (score >= 150) {
                editor.putString("page", "com.twigofknowledge.variablebuttonpractice.page6");
                editor.apply();

            } else if (score <= 150) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = saveGame.edit();
                editor.putString("page", "com.twigofknowledge.variablebuttonpractice.page5");
                editor.apply();

            }
            Intent gotopage = new Intent();
            gotopage.setClassName("com.twigofknowledge.variablebuttonpractice", page);
            startActivity(gotopage);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are not updating `page` variable, change to code below
@Override

```
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (score >= 150) {
            page = "com.twigofknowledge.variablebuttonpractice.page6";
            editor.putString("page", "com.twigofknowledge.variablebuttonpractice.page6");
            editor.apply();

        } else if (score <= 150) {
            page = "com.twigofknowledge.variablebuttonpractice.page5";
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = saveGame.edit();
            editor.putString("page", "com.twigofknowledge.variablebuttonpractice.page5");
            editor.apply();

        }
        Intent gotopage = new Intent();
        gotopage.setClassName("com.twigofknowledge.variablebuttonpractice", page);
        startActivity(gotopage);
    }
```

Comment: Yes, thanks you!  That worked out exactly right.  I really appreciate your time and help for a random stranger asking rookie questions.  Goodwill to you!